# After booting into Windows, Ubuntu no longer recognises wifi adaptor

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, wireless, 20.04, windows-10

I have a dual system (Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04), on my **Vivobook ASUS X571GD**. I've only been using my Linux on this computer so far and the wifi adapter worked without any issues, however, once I booted into Windows, the clever cookie obviously hogged the adapter with it's own drivers and now when I boot back into Ubuntu, it swears that no wifi adapter exists. I don't have access to internet on the Linux system so I can't go on mad driver hunt and I also currently have no flash drive to transfer any drivers (yay I'm stuck in quarantine, no going out).

Is there a way for me to just reinstall the drivers my Ubuntu previously used (I assume it didn't delete them)? Or some way to roll back the change Windows made? And above all, is there any way to stop this from happening every time I boot into Windows?

I have a **Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9461**, if that's of any use. I bought my laptop in South Africa, which I believe might change the type of chipset my wifi adapter uses.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This seems to have worked for the moment. Downloaded the necessary drivers to keep the locally just in case. Thanks so much!